# Conexion con Web Service

Tags: c#, web, vb, servicio

estoy consumiendo un Web Service, pero resulta que a veces dicho web service tiene problemas no logro conectarme ya q se cae, tengo un metodo que pille en internet para verificar si existe conexion o no, pero cuando no la hay se esperando como en un ciclo repetitivo.
quiesiera saber si hay la manera de establecer un cierto tiempo para que intente conectarse y si no lo logra que retorne algun tipo de mensaje o q se salga

gracias de antemano...

```
    Public Function VerificarConexionURL(ByVal mURL As String) As Boolean
  Dim Peticion As System.Net.WebRequest
  Dim Respuesta As System.Net.WebResponse
  Try
     Peticion = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(mURL)
     Respuesta = Peticion.GetResponse()
     Return True
  Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
     If ex.Status = Net.WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure Then
        Return False
     End If
     Return False
  End Try
```

End Function

Comment: Manda una petición simple con un timeout corto y así sabrás si está en línea o no. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer uso de un objeto `timer` que espere unos segundos antes de volver a reintentar o quizas usar el `Thread.Sleep()` para detener el codigo un tiempo.

```
Public Sub PingWithRetry()

    Dim i As Intenger = 0

    While i < 3
       If VerificarConexionURL(url) Then
          Return
       End If
       Thread.Sleep(3000)
       i=i+1
    End While

    Throw New Exception("Se excedio el maximo de reintentos")

End Sub
```

en este caso va a reintentar 3 veces, con una espera de 3 seg entre cada validacion, si se llega al maximo se genera un exception

Comment: Una leve corrección, el parámetro de Thread.Sleep() es en milisegundos, para esperar 30 segundos deberá enviar 30,000

Comment: es verdad, gracias por la correcion, voy a arreglarlo en la respuesta